# Insert selected value from select tag into database

Tags: php, html, sql, pdo

I have a database table with the names and locations of schools. Looks like this

```
id      name                           location
1   Federal University of tech        California
2.  Massachusetts Inst of tech            Boston
```

I'm populating a select tag with the names of these schools using this table. And it works fine. Each user is supposed to select his/her school when creating his/her profile. However when the form is submitted, only the first word in the school name gets inserted. e.g for Federal University of tech; only Federal is inserted into the database and for Massachusetts Inst of tech only Massachusetts is inserted - and so on -  as opposed to the full name of the school. How do i get the full names of the selected school inserted? The code(page.php):

```
<?php
//Getting names of schools to populate select tag

$stmt = $db->query("SELECT name from schools order by name ASC");

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
$major = $_POST['major'];
$university = $_POST['university'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

$stmts = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO profile (university, major email)") VALUES (:university, :major, :email);
$stmts->execute(array(':university' => $university, ':major' => $major, ':email' => $email));
}

?>

//THE HTML FORM
<form action = "page.php" method = "post">

<label>University:

<?php
echo '<select title = "Select one" name= "university"></select>';
echo '<option value="">--please select--</option>';

while ($rows = $stmt->fetch[PDO::FETCH_ASSOC])
echo '<option value = '.$rows['name'].'>'.$rows['name'].'</option>';

echo '</select>';

?>
//other form elements
</label>
</form>
```

Comment: You have a comma missing in `(university, major email)` unless that's a copy/paste typo.

Comment: yes it's a typo..edited it..

Comment: Check your column lengths then. They may be too small.

Comment: Also, you should add some bracing `{}` around your `while` loop and changing `fetch[PDO::FETCH_ASSOC])` to `while ($rows = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))` that could be a factor. As per the manual http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

Comment: Can you show how you  are populating the SELECT?

Comment: ok..i'm using varchar(250) for the university column in the profile table as well as the schools table. i think that's pretty large...

Comment: Does anything get populated from the dropdown?

Comment: @rontornambe yeah its shown in the code. i'm populating the select with that while loop..

Comment: @Fred-ii- i formatted the syntax but it's still the same...

Comment: @Fred-ii-yes.. as i stated, the dropdown is populated perfectly with names as written in the database. But when a user selects a school to be inserted in his/her profile, only the first word inthe school name is inserted..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem lies in the the way you have written *value* attribute for the *option* tag.
The suggestion is to put values-with-spaces in double quotes.
Like:

```
echo '<option value = "Massachusetts Inst of tech">Massachusetts Inst of tech</option>';
```

But what is getting passed is this because double quotes have been neglected:

```
echo '<option value = "Massachusetts">Massachusetts Inst of tech</option>';
```

You might want to check out this line:

```
echo '<option value = '.$rows['name'].'>'.$rows['name'].'</option>';
```

and correct with this one:

```
echo '<option value = "'.$rows['name'].'">'.$rows['name'].'</option>';
```

Comment: Great, but you're going to hit another snag when you try to INSERT. @ss_millionaire

Comment: @Fred-ii-oh okay..what kind of snag..?

Comment: @ss_millionaire AKumar will know. I have to go get supper ready.

Comment: @AKumar do u know d snag Fred -ii- is talking about?

Comment: @ss_millionaire You mean to tell me that this actually works? `$stmts = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO profile (university, major email)") VALUES (:university, :major, :email);` that would only generate a parse error.

Comment: @Fred-ii- just noticed the quotation marks and parentheses are a bit misplaced. it should be `$stmts = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO profile (university, major, email) VALUES (:university, :major, :email)");`    It's a copy-paste error. Was well formatted in the actual code. Thanks.

Comment: @ss_millionaire That's why you should always post actual code. It really leaves the guesswork out of it. Someone else would've most likely have said the very same thing I said. In the future, do post your actual code, because this could very well make the difference between getting answers and a question voted to close because of many factors; that one being one of them. ;-) That's why I was right about the parse error that would have been generated from your posted code.